# Does hash_equals compare strings hashed with `sha512`?

Tags: php, bcrypt, sha512

I need to store a token in database and match the token supplied by user with database token, for hashing token I am using `sha512`. And I compare both tokens with simple `==` operator.

```
if($usertoken == $dbtoken) {

}
```

But someone suggested me to use [`hash_equals()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) instead as it will prevent timing attacks (extra security), with `bcrypt` to hash token. So I just want to know does hash_equals compare strings hashed with `sha512` or I have to use bcrypt?

Comment: I would think this could be easily tested, no?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I thought questioning would also bring out any flaws if any :)

Comment: How does a timing attack against a sha512-hashed string even work? (Ignoring for a moment that DB I/O would probably mask any timings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its name, this function has **nothing to do** with hashing.

It compares two strings for equality, nothing more, nothing less. You can feed it two strings containing any arbitrary sequence of characters, whether they represent a plain-text password or a password hashed with the algorithm of your choice, be it `bcrypt` or `sha512`.